# Is it possible to use asp:RegularExpressionValidator to validate phone number with at least 10 digits AND allow white spaces in-betweenBUTnotcounted

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I searched the Stackoverflow and it seems that the other answers don't quite fit my question.

I wonder whether this is possible if I only use asp:RegularExpressionValidator to validate phone numbers with at least 10 digits AND allow white spaces in-between the digits BUT those white spaces are not counted.

This is what I am using for now

```
"^[0-9]{10,}$"
```

Thank you.

Comment: `^(?=(?:\s*\d){10,})[\s\d]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
@"^(?=(?:\s*\d){10,})[\s\d]+$"
```

OR

```
@"^(?=(?: *\d){10})[ \d]+$"
```

Positive lookahead at the start asserts that the string going to be matched must contain at-least 10 digits. `(?:\s*\d){10}` exactly 10 times of (zero or more spaces and a digit).

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jS6cE1/1)

If you don't want to match the string which contain leading or trailing spaces then add word boundaries at the start and at the end.

```
^(?=(?: *\d){10})\b[ \d]+\b$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jS6cE1/2)

Comment: Fantastic~!!! I was opening the same website to test your regular expressions and suddenly saw you have already updated your post with a Demo on the same website, cool! I saw that you use /gm, how do I apply the /gm inside the asp:RegularExpressionValidator?

Comment: i think `m` modifier would be enough. `@"(?m)^(?=(?: *\d){10})[ \d]+$"`

Comment: Hi Avinash, thank you for your post! How to use the /gm stuff in the asp validator control? I tried it this way : <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... ValidationExpression="^(?=(?: *\d){10})[ \d]+$/gm" /> it doesn't work. After I removed the /gm, it starts to work.

Comment: you don't need to include `/gm`. It's not a right way to include modifiers inside the regex. Recommended way of using modifiers inside regex is like `(?m)`. By putting it at the start, it enables the multiline mode. And note that you can't enable global modifier like this way. Most languages (_including C#_) enable `g` modifier by default. You don't need to include that.